# Flutter | Android SQLite database inspection with Chrome DevTools | VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, sqflite

AndroidStudio has the database inspector which is a great and easy tool to view DB content.
On VSCode I haven't yet found an easy to average solution to work!
I'm using **SQFlite** package

This tool doesn't work and not maintained:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stetho

And this one has lots of unnecessary steps and tools for my simple task:
https://pub.dev/packages/appspector

Is there any way to inspect the SQLite database with ChromeDevTool or any other way?

Comment: I'm looking for an inspector tool as well. Have you found anything that works for you?

Comment: Any workaround?